# Startup applications never launch

Tags: 20.10, startup-applications

I have Stacer installed, and enabled as a startup application...however no matter how many times I restart my computer it never starts up with it... Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if this is the same problem, but take a look at this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301862/no-system-tray-detected-after-latest-update-for-some-applications/1301879#1301879)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.10 groovy gorilla or whatever it is.