# Zoom won't close and more common issues

Tags: 20.04, crash, zoom-meeting

I'm an Ubuntu 20.04 user and I've been experimenting some issues I won't normally experiment on Windows while using Zoom application.

**Installation:**

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

**Some Problems:**
First of all, when I close all the windows related to Zoom via  [image: Top Bar]
All the instances disappear from the task bar, but the proccess won't end on the system monitor as shown below:

[image: Zoom on System Monitor Still Open]

This wouldn't be a problem if I didn't need to end it before opening Zoom again (which is another problem by itself). Every time I close all the Zoom related windows I have to go to system monitor to end the process. Otherwise, If I try to open again the application I won't get any answer from the computer.

Finally, there are some cases when Zoom randomly crashes showing the following message:

[image]

However, when I open the system monitor the `zoom` process is still running, so if I try to open the application again I get no response until I kill the process on system monitor.

Comment: I do not use zoom but after closing it does it have an icon on the top task bar? If like another program VLC it does then its not fully closed you need to right click and close that as well. Also I do not think this is what you meant to say *I've been experimenting

Comment: No, all the instances of Zoom seem closed on the task bar, thanks for the clarification. I'll add that on my post.

Comment: @user68186 so I was half right :)

Comment: You are right, I'll edit my post and try your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Zoom is difficult to close

The close button ❌ on the top right corner of the Zoom window does not actually close the app. It minimizes the app and removed the app icon from the Dash/Dock (the left panel in Ubuntu). Normally Zoom icon in the system-trey/app-inidiator (top panel) would alert you that Zoom is not closed and close Zoom from there. However, a bug is preventing Zoom icon from appearing in the system-trey.

### Check Zoom Settings

First, let us change the default setting so that you are visually reminded that Zoom is not closed when you click the ❌ button.

Click on the Zoom settings cog icon on the top right of the Zoom window.

[image]

On the General tab, uncheck **When closed minimize windows to the notification area instead of the task bar**.

[image]

Note, this will not close zoom when you click on the close icon ❌. But now you will see that Zoom was not really closed. You can close Zoom by using the context menu of the Zoom icon on the Dock.

[image]

### There is a bug in `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`

This bug prevents the Zoom icon showing up in the system trey if Zoom is set to start automatically on login.

See [No system tray detected after latest update for some applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301862/no-system-tray-detected-after-latest-update-for-some-applications/1301879#1301879) for various workarounds for this bug.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep, it worked. It was pretty easy to fix thanks.